# Unable to access allure dashboard

Tags: allure

I built the image from dockerfile where all robot framework dependency and allure command line installed.And then i deployed the image through cron job to Aks. Getting allure results and allure report successful. allure results and allure reports generated in directory in Azure storage. But when click on html link in browser gettin blanc screen and in logs getting error like below
Starting we server...
Main: logging initialised @628ms to org.ecliose.jetty.util.log.stdErrLog can not open browser because this capability is not supported on your platform. You can use the below link to open the report manually.server started ...

This link is also showing blanc. Can you guide me how can I access allure dashboard on browser

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions here?